# Using git and github to share a folder content that has to be updated daily

Tags: backup, git, github

I have a folder that I want to publicly share with others, the content of the folder suppose to be updated daily: some files gonna be changed, some are deleted, some are added.
I would like to use **GitHub** for that and create a cronjob that supposes to handle the repository updates.
What kind of **git commands** do I have to use if I always want to have an exact copy of the local folder on my git repository.

**This is the code that I am planning to use but I have doubts about locally deleted files (if it is cover them or not)‍♂️:**

```
cd ~/myfolder
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "$current_date"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is almost correct for the initial setup of your repository, there's a few more steps you need to add to the end:

```
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository-name.git #Edit this to match your Github repo
git push -u origin main
```

The first line I've added sets the branch on git (Github default branch is `main`), the second line sets the remote origin, and the final line pushes your folder to Github.

The script you call from crontab should look like this:

```
cd ~/myfolder
git add .
git commit -a -m "$current_date"
git push
```

Assuming you named it `upload-script.sh`, this is the crontab entry, which will run at every minute (the fastest interval crontab allows) with no output:

```
* * * * * ~/upload-script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm not sure if you can ger rate-limited by Github for this, so you might need to decrease the speed of pushes. You can generate crontab entries using [crontab generator](https://crontab-generator.org/) if this is the case.

And for reference, here's Github's documentation on how to set up a remote repository (helpful for debugging git issues):
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your overall answer.
I have noticed that the .git folder is used a lot of space.
I was doing some research and I found 2 more commands to reduce the size of the folder which is:

`git fsck`
`git prune`

My question is should I use them? as I said I don't need any history of the files. Also, it would be wonderful if there is a way to get the repository without .git folder or with a minimum size. Of course, I can delete the folder after but I am worried about the bandwidth which I would like to save. Thank you!

Comment: Is that make sense to make the code like that:

`cd ~/myfolder;
git fsck;
git prune;
git add .;
git commit -a -m "$current_date";
git push`'

Comment: Honestly, if you’re not needing the history then there’s better methods to do this than Git (e.g. cloud storage, localexpose services), but your changes should keep the size of .git to a minimum. Also, Git doesn’t upload the entire repo every time you push, only the files which have changed since the last push (see this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005031/what-does-git-push-do-exactly ).

Comment: Also I noticed you’re fairly new to SE, so welcome :) if my answer fulfilled what you need, please accept it so that other people can see what helped you.